# In R, how do I classify each row of a data frame based on the bin its values fall into?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, grouping, binning

In R, I want to classify each rows of the data frame by binning the values and using the number (sum) of values in each bin to assign them into 2 groups (classes) by using if-else logic.

- Within an R for-loop, I used the R cut and split commands to bin the
  values by row.
- The bins (ranges) are: 1..9, 10..19, 20..29, 30..39, 40..49.
- If a row contains 1 pair of values falling in the same bin (range),
  say 10..19, then it should be classified as "P". If it contains 2
  pairs falling into 2 different bins (ranges), then they should be
  classified as "PP".
- Then I created 2 new variables named p and pp by using hard-coded
  conditions/rules. The values in the variables are either TRUE or
  FALSE, depending whether the n-th row meet the those rules.
- Finally, I used p and pp as conditions in the if-else statement to
  assign each row to either class P (1st row), or class PP (2nd row).

First, I created a data frame x:

```
n1 <- c(1, 7); n2 <- c(2, 11); n3 <- c(10, 14); n4 <- c(23, 32); n5 <- c(37, 37); n6 <- c(45, 41)
x <- data.frame(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6)
x
  n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6
1  1  2 10 23 37 45
2  7 11 14 32 37 41
```

The 1st row should be classified as "P", because it has 1 pair of values (1, 2) falling in the same bin 1..10.
The 2nd row should be classified as "PP", because it has 2 pairs of values (11, 14 and 32, 37) falling in 2 bins: 10..19 and 30..39, accordingly.

So, after creating the data frame x, I created a for-loop:

```
for(i in nrow(x)){

# binning the data:
  bins <- split(as.numeric(x[i, ]), cut(as.numeric(x[i, ]), c(0, 9, 19, 29, 39, 49)))
  # creating the rule for p (1 pair of numbers falling in the same range)
  p <- (sum(lengths(bins) == 2) == 1 & sum(lengths(bins) == 1) == 4)
  # creating the rule for pp (2 different pairs, each has 2 numbers falling in the same range)
  pp <- (sum(lengths(bins) == 2) == 2 & sum(lengths(bins) == 1) == 2 & sum(lengths(bins) == 0) == 1)

  if(p){
    x$types <- "P"
  } else if(pp){
    x$types <- "PP"
  } else{
    stop("error")
  }
  }

print(x)
```

I want to create a new column named types, holding the class P or PP:

```
  n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 types
1  1  2 10 23 37 45 P
2  7 11 14 32 37 41 PP
```

Instead the code returned only PP:

```
  n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 types
1  1  2 10 23 37 45 PP
2  7 11 14 32 37 41 PP
```

This is because the loop runs twice over the rows. But if it runs only once, all the rows are classified as "P", instead of "PP". I expect it's something very simple, just was not able to figure it out so far.

Comment: Maybe simply use `cut` and set `labels`? Is there a reason for applying a loop?

Comment: for-loop is not necessary, but using labels: I don't know because I want to use the rules as they are defined when creating variables p and pp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your `for` loop is that you don't use `i` when you assign `type`. `x$types <- "P"` assigns the entire `types` column to be `"P"`. `x$types <- "PP"` assigns the whole `types` column to be `"PP"`. So, whatever the last result is, that will be the value for your entire column.

Also, using the *full row* `x[i, ]` is dangerous after you add the `types` column. Presumably you don't want to try to convert the "P" and "PP" values of `types` to numeric and bin them. I would suggest making `types` a separate vector, and only adding it as a column *after* the loop. Before the loop: `types <- chracter(nrow(x))`. Inside the loop: `types[i] <-` instead of `x$types <-`. After the loop, `x$types <- types`.

You are also making the classic syntax error of `for (i in nrow(x))` when you mean `for (i in 1:nrow(x))`.

Fixing all of these:

```
n1 <- c(1, 7); n2 <- c(2, 11); n3 <- c(10, 14); n4 <- c(23, 32); n5 <- c(37, 37); n6 <- c(45, 41)
x <- data.frame(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6)

types <- character(nrow(x))

for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  # binning the data:
  bins <- split(as.numeric(x[i, ]), cut(as.numeric(x[i, ]), c(0, 9, 19, 29, 39, 49)))
  # creating the rule for p (1 pair of numbers falling in the same range)
  p <- (sum(lengths(bins) == 2) == 1 & sum(lengths(bins) == 1) == 4)
  # creating the rule for pp (2 different pairs, each has 2 numbers falling in the same range)
  pp <- (sum(lengths(bins) == 2) == 2 & sum(lengths(bins) == 1) == 2 & sum(lengths(bins) == 0) == 1)

  if(p){
    types[i] <- "P"
  } else if(pp){
    types[i] <- "PP"
  } else{
    stop("error")
  }
}

x$types <- types
x
#   n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 types
# 1  1  2 10 23 37 45     P
# 2  7 11 14 32 37 41    PP
```

Comment: Thank you for the things that you pointed out. I would hardly figured them out myself. So, now it works. Strange that the complete code, which I did not provide for brevity, works better without x$types <- types.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty

```
x['types'] <- apply(x, 1, function(a) {stringr::str_replace_all(paste(+(table(floor(a/10)) > 1), collapse=""), c('1'='P','0'=''))})
```

Unpacking

`floor(a/10)` converts to *bin*
`table(...) > 1` counts *bins* and returns `TRUE` for those that > 1
`+(...)` converts logical `TRUE/FALSE` to `1/0`
`paste(..., collapse="")` concatenates vector of strings to single string without spaces
`str_replace_all(..., c('1'='P', ...))` replaces all substrings using pattern-replacements defined as `'old'='new'`

Result

```
  n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 types
1  1  2 10 23 37 45     P
2  7 11 14 32 37 41    PP
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that it's not a binary case (i. e. if not p, than pp). I mean, it's not: if x < 1 do this, if x > 1 to that . I just did not pasted the entire code to make things simpler. As shown in the code, the rules are hard-coded, like templates:    
    p <- (sum(lengths(bins) == 2) == 1 & sum(lengths(bins) == 1) == 4)
    pp <- (sum(lengths(bins) == 2) == 2 & sum(lengths(bins) == 1) == 2 & sum(lengths(bins) == 0) == 1)
What want to know is why it's not working with the for-loop and how I can fix this. It might be not with a for-loop, but I want to preserve the rules.